# Bring versus Take: specific example

Tags: word-choice, verbs, deictic-verbs

I understand that the difference between 'bring' and 'take' is the direction of movement in relation to a point of reference. You ask people to bring things to the place you are, and you take things to the place you are going. In other words, you use to 'bring' indicates that something is carried by the speaker to the listener or vice versa. And 'take' if the place something is being carried to is away from both the speaker and listener.

So here is my scenario. I found myself a table at a food bar, and went up to the counter with the intention of asking for the food to be served to me at my table. So should I tell them to 'TAKE them to my table' or 'BRING them to my table'? Because at the time of asking I wasn't at my table, but at the counter, so technically from there it would a movement away from where I was. However, I would definitely be at my table when the food gets served. So which verb would suit the situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on where you are when the action occurs.

If you go to the counter and ask someone to move food *at the counter* to your table (at that moment), then:

> Please **take** these items to my table.

But if you go to the counter and ask someone to move food to your table at a later time, then:

> When these items are prepared, please **bring** them to my table.

The fact that you asked in advance makes no difference.